# How to "Print Out" the data of a QStandardItem

Tags: c++, qt, qstandarditem

Is there a way to print the data of a QstandardItem out, say I have;

```
QList<QStandardItem*> testQList;
QString yay = "!Yay";
QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(yay);
testQList.append(item);

qDebug() << testQList;
```

I just get the memory addres, `(0x409bd00)` I cannot dereference the list either.

Comment: Hi Neil, thats the first thing I tried, I get `illegal indirection` and `<< illegal for class`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this because you try to print whole list with objects, it is not list with strings. In this case `qDebug` always prints memory address so you should use loop and `text()` method(iterate throw list).

```
for(int i = 0; i<testQList.size();i++)
{
   qDebug() << testQList.at(i)->text();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QList>
#include <QDebug>

class QStandardItem
{
    QString mStr;
public:
    QStandardItem(QString str)
    {
        mStr = str;
    }

    QString toString()
    {
        return mStr;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QList<QStandardItem*> testQList;
    QString yay = "!Yay";
    QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(yay);
    testQList.append(item);

    for(int i = 0; i<testQList.size();i++)
    {
       qDebug() << testQList.at(i)->toString();
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```